# get the date from database where date is 10 days ago with laravel

Tags: laravel, date

i need to get payments where the payment date is done before 100 days ago, I have a (date) when make a payment, and i tried this, but doesn't working:

```
$statusSearch = Payment::where('date', '<', strtotime('-10 Days'))->get();
```

Comment: try $statusSearch = Payment::where('date', '>', Carbon::now()->subDays(100)->startOfDay())->get();

Comment: What is the type of your "date" column ? an integer containing a unix timestamp, or a date or a datetime ? if it is a date, just do `Payment::where('date', '<=', date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-10 Days')))->get();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Carbon subDays() like below:

```
$statusSearch = Payment::where('date', '<=', Carbon::now()->subDays(10)->toDateTimeString())->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's use [whereDate](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#additional-where-clauses), because we need to compare dates, and Carbon to have DateInterval:

```
$tenDaysAgo = Carbon::now()->subDays(10);
$statusSearch = Payment::whereDate('date', '<', $tenDaysAgo)->get();
```

Then, don't forget to go in the `Payment` model and cast `date` column to `date`:

```
protected $casts = [
    'date' => 'date',
];
```

Also I suggest you to rename this column to something else, just to now have issue in the near future during the query.

Comment: i am not sure if it is worked, but when I make it like this, it give me one day ago:
 $tenDaysAgo = Carbon::now()->subDays(0); as i understood from implementation in my case

Comment: `subDays(0)` shouldn't do anything